# Differential Equations Hermitian Matrix Proof

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

I would like some help with the following proof below. Thanks for any help in advance.

Prove that if $u(t) ∈ \mathbb C^N$ is a solution to the initial value problem $iu’ =Au$, $u(0)=u_0$,
where $A$ is hermitian, then $||u(t)|| = ||u_0||$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wealll, note that for Hermitian $A = A^\dagger$, $iA$ is skew-Hermitian:

$(iA)^\dagger = \bar i A^\dagger = -i A^\dagger = -iA, \tag{1}$

and if $iA$ is skew-Hermitian, certainly $B = -iA$ is as well, $B^\dagger = -B$, and note further that the equation

$iu' = Au \tag{2}$

may be written as

$u' = \dfrac{1}{i}Au = -iAu = Bu. \tag{3}$

The solution to (3) with initial condition $u(0) = u_0$ is

$u(t) = e^{Bt}u_0, \tag{4}$

as is well-known.  Then

$\langle u(t), u(t) \rangle = \langle e^{Bt}u_0, e^{Bt}u_0 \rangle = \langle (e^{Bt})^\dagger e^{Bt} u_0, u_0 \rangle = \langle e^{B^\dagger t} e^{Bt}u_0, u_0 \rangle $
$= \langle e^{-Bt} e^{Bt} u_0, u_0 \rangle = \langle u_0, u_0 \rangle, \tag{5}$

since $e^{-Bt} e^{Bt} = I$.  ***QED.***

Hope this helps.  Cheers.

And As Ever,

***Fiat Lux!!!***